# Regex validation in struts2

Tags: regex, validation, struts2, operator-keyword, requiredfieldvalidator

I need to validate an code field in struts2 with xml file validation.
I've got the regex expression, and it works.
I would like to add a condition: It's also ok if the field is blank.

I've tried to use an AND operator in this way:

```
    <field name="codeFiscale">
    <field-validator type="regex">
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[^(?=^$)(?=[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[abcdehlmprstABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3})[a-zA-Z]{1})$]]></param>
        <message key="error.CF.invalid" />
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OR operator

```
<field name="codeFiscale">
  <field-validator type="regex">
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[(?:^\\s*$)|(^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[abcdehlmprstABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3})[a-zA-Z]{1}$)]]></param>
    <message key="error.CF.invalid" />
  </field-validator>
</field>
```

Comment: Thanks.
it works also with this code:
(^$|^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[abcdehlmprstABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3})[a-zA-Z]{1}$)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean an OR operator? You want "either your first experession OR blank".

Try something like:

```
(?:firstExpression)?(blank?)
```

Comment: no, I mean AND operator.
There's also a NOT: (![CDATA).

So the error will appear only if both expressions are not true

Answer (score 0):

i will work fine

`<param name="expression">^[0-9]{10}$</param>`  there is a bug.

```
<field name="contact">
    <field-validator type="regex">
        <param name="regex">^[0-9]{10}$</param>
        <message>Invalid contact Number(10 digit)</message>         
    </field-validator>
</field>
```